# randomly select n rows from each block - pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

Let's say I have a pandas DataFrame named *df* that looks like this

```
father_name   child_name
Robert        Julian
Robert        Emily
Robert        Dan
Carl          Jack
Carl          Rose
John          Lucy
John          Mark
John          Alysha
Paul          Christopher
Paul          Thomas
Robert        Kevin
Carl          Elisabeth
```

where I know for sure that each father has **at least** 2 children.

I would like to obtain a DataFrame where each father has **exactly** 2 of his children, and those two children are selected at random. An example output would be

```
father_name   child_name
Robert        Emily
Robert        Kevin
Carl          Jack
Carl          Elisabeth
John          Alysha
John          Mark
Paul          Thomas
Paul          Christopher
```

How can I do that?

Comment: With code, I guess. What have you attempted from your research around this problem? Did you get errors?

Comment: Low effort Mondays have now extended to low effort December I suppose... Please see [ask] and provide a [MCVE] of your coding attempt.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply [DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) on the grouped data. It takes the parameter n which you can set to 2

```
df.groupby('father_name').child_name.apply(lambda x: x.sample(n=2))\
.reset_index(1, drop = True).reset_index()


father_name child_name
0   Carl    Elisabeth
1   Carl    Jack
2   John    Mark
3   John    Lucy
4   Paul    Thomas
5   Paul    Christopher
6   Robert  Emily
7   Robert  Julian
```